# Error: Bundling failed - While trying to resolve module 'react-native-firebase'

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to use Firebase Authentication and am getting the below error when running `react-native run-android`. The error is happening in the node terminal that pops up when \react-native\scripts\..\local-cli\cli.js script runs. I'm following the docs for the [initial setup](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/initial-setup), [android setup](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/android), and [auth setup](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/auth/android). Where is the dist/ folder supposed to come from? Thanks in advance!

error: bundling failed: Error: While trying to resolve module `react-native-firebase` from file `D:\Temp\projects\app\src\components\LoginView.js`, the package `D:\Temp\projects\app\node_modules\react-native-firebase\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`D:\Temp\projects\app\node_modules\react-native-firebase\dist\index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- `D:\Temp\projects\app\node_modules\react-native-firebase\dist\index.js(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
- `D:\Temp\projects\app\node_modules\react-native-firebase\dist\index.js\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
  at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (D:\Temp\projects\app\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:61:15)
  at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\Temp\projects\app\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:219:16)
  at Object.resolve (D:\Temp\projects\app\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:141:30)
  at dependencies.map.result (D:\Temp\projects\app\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:373:31)
  at Array.map ()
  at resolveDependencies (D:\Temp\projects\app\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:369:18)
  at D:\Temp\projects\app\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:188:33
  at Generator.next ()
  at step (D:\Temp\projects\app\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:298:30)
  at D:\Temp\projects\app\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:309:15

package.json:

`{"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
    "react-native": "0.57.4",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.49.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728"
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by re-running `react-native link react-native-firebase`. The /dist folder showed up in the node_modules/react-native-firebase directory once this command runs successfully.

Comment: How can I run this command and where?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem and the accepted answer did not solve it.  I found that the cache was corrupted because of a failed download of `npm install firebase --save`. So running the following solved the issue:

```
npm uninstall react-native-firebase
yarn start --reset-cache
yarn --reset-cache
npm install react-native-firebase --save
```